# Get document count list in a javascript class

Tags: javascript, html

> This is the html

```
<ul id="List">
   <li><h2>Numeros Primos</h2></li>
   <li>Hello World</li>
   <li>Not Work</li>
</ul>
<p id="count"></p>
```

---

> This is the javascript

```
class List {
        static Restart() {
            document.getElementById("List").innerHTML = "<li><h2>Numeros Primos</h2></li>";
        }
        static add(Number) {
            document.getElementById("List").innerHTML += "<li>" + Number + "</li>"
        }
        get count() {
            return document.getElementById("List").childElementCount
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = List.count;
    // return undefined
```

> PROBLEM
>
> > I can't get count number in the list
> >
> > it return "undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**make count static :)**

```js
class List {
        static Restart() {
            document.getElementById("List").innerHTML = "<li><h2>Numeros Primos</h2></li>";
        }
        static add(Number) {
            document.getElementById("List").innerHTML = document.getElementById("List").innerHTML + "<li>" + Number + "</li>"
        }
        static get count() {
            return document.getElementById("List").childElementCount;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = List.count;
```

```html
<ul id="List">
   <li><h2>Numeros Primos</h2></li>
   <li>Hello World</li>
   <li>Not Work</li>
</ul>
<p id="count"></p>
```